# create number pattern into a string vector

Tags: c++

new to programming so I apologize if this has been answered before...I have tried searching with almost zero luck.
I am trying to create a number pattern like 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4 etc;
I have gotten to that point but I need to put it into a string vector so that if the user inputs 5, the string vector elements are 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5

```
void print_vectorStr(vector<string> &vec, string sep = "")
{
    cout << "\nThe vector string elements are: ";
    for (auto elem : vec)
    {
        cout << elem << sep;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_vector(vector<int> &vec, string sep = "")
{
    cout << "\nThe vector integer elements are: ";
    for (auto elem : vec)
    {
        cout << elem << sep;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    cout << "insert n \n";
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> vec(n);
    vector<string> vecString;
    for (int i = 1; i <= vec.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }

    print_vector(vec, " ");
    print_vectorStr(vecString, " ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once you know `n`, why use vectors or strings for *any* of this? I would think a few loops (or some crafty library function calls) is all that would be required to produce *output* of the ilk you seem to be seeking. I say 'seem' because we're not sure what that is, and the code, with those appending separators, seems to be generating something beyond just strings of digits.

Comment: Stick to the nested loop so you understand what the crafty library functions will be doing for now. Loop `i == 1` to `n` on the outer loop and `j = 0; j < i` on the inner (or just do `int j = 1;` and `while (j--)` to loop `i` times) and for your `std::string` (`std::vector` not needed) just `mystring.push_back (i + '0')` where you have `cout << i ...` now. (adding `'0'` to the integer value of `i` gives the ASCII value for that number. See [ASCII Table Description](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: The only time you need `std::vector` is if `n` can be greater than `9`. If that is a possibility then use `std::vector<std::string>` and to add to `myvector` use `myvector.push_back(std::to_string(i));`

Comment: Trying to run a Google search for "how do I do a <high level problem> in C++" will never find anything useful (Google is not a repository of C++ code). Instead you need to first take a piece of paper, and write down in short, brief, sentences in plain English a logical step-by-step process for implementing the <high level problem> in C++.Then, translate it directly into C++, but if in the process of translating one of the short, brief, sentences into code you get stuck, then googling ***that*** will be far more productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a vector of strings, and need to reproduce the output in a comma-separated pattern, you can do something simple like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main () {
  
  size_t n = 0;                           /* unsigned variable for n */
  std::vector<std::string> pattern{};     /* vector of strings */
  
  std::cout << "enter n: ";
  if (!(std::cin >> n)) {                 /* validate EVERY user-input */
    std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++) {           /* loop n times from 1 */
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {          /* loop i times */
      pattern.push_back(std::to_string(i));   /* add i i's to string */
    }
  }
  
  /* loop over each string in pattern with index to control ',' output */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++) {
    if (i) {                    /* if not first string */
      std::cout.put(',');       /* output ',' */
    }
    std::cout << pattern[i];    /* output string */
  }
  std::cout.put('\n');          /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

Note above you must **validate EVERY user-input**. Otherwise, what would happen if the user slipped and tapped `'t'` instead of `5`? Also note, to control the `','` separator for output, you can either keep a counter and use a *range-based* `for` loop, or, since you need a counter anyway, just use a normal conditioned `for` loop.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/num_pattern
enter n: 2
1,2,2
```

```
$ ./bin/num_pattern
enter n: 5
1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5
```

or

```
$ ./bin/num_pattern
enter n: t
error: invalid input.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pretty close to solution like this in my previous attempt and what I was messing up on was the vector didn't need to be an int data type. Had I realized that, I would've done push back into the vector once I had what I wanted.

Comment: You are quite welcome. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Very good solution, as always. Just as an additional information. There is also a O(n) approach, by simply calculating the value. Please see my answer below. Though, the `sqrt` function may slow it down. But double nested loops with `push_back`s may also slow down for big numbers . . .

Answer (score 1):

This is more a less a mathematical problem.

Of course everybody will implement the naive solution with a double nested loop. It is easy and very very fast.

But there is also an analytical solution. We can simply calculate the value of the series using a simple formula. All is based on the arithmetic series.

Let us look at the series and count the number of occurences of the digits:

```
Series:            1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6
Count of numbers:  1  2    3      4        5          6
```

If we want to know, how many numbers the series contains, we need to add up `1+2+3+4+5+6`. Or more general, `1+2+3+...+k`. And this can be easily calculated with a well known formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)):

```
sum = k * (k + 1) / 2
```

If we want to know, which is the first occurence of a number (k+1), then we know, that before this number, there will be `k * (k + 1) / 2`other numbers.

Example: How many numbers are in front of the first occurence of 7?

```
Series:            1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6           7
Count of numbers:  1  2    3      4        5          6         1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21
```

So, 21 numbers are in front of that. Ok, now more general. Let's set the sum formular in an equation to equal n and the play a little bit. So, before our number k=7 there are there (one less) `k * (k-1) / 2` values. Let us use this and put it into an equation for any number n=k+1 and play a little bit:

```
k(k-1)/2 = n
k^2-k = 2n
k^2-k-2n = 0

Solve the standard quadratic equation for K (with p=-1 and q=-2n)

k =  1/2 + sqrt( (-1*-1)/4 - (-2n))
k =  1/2 + sqrt( 1/4 +2n)
k =  1/2 + sqrt( 1 + 8n)
k =  (1 + sqrt( 1 + 8n))/2
```

So, some simple mathematics: if we do this as integer division, we get the count of occurrences for each number. This gives us the final formula for the number at index n:

```
(int)((1 + std::sqrt(1 + 8 * n)) / 2)
```

Please note: index starts with 1 here!!!

Cool. We can calculate the number at a given position or for all positions. And we know, how many numbers we need to store.

If we want to store this in a `std::vector`, then we can define the vector together with the size `(k * (k + 1) / 2)`.

And we can use the above function to fill the vector with `std::generate` with all the needed numbers.

The result is a completely loopless and very simple piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // Get, check and update user input
    if (int k{}; (std::cin >> k) and (k > 0)) {

        // Create a vector with the needed number of elements
        std::vector<std::string> pattern(k * (k + 1) / 2);

        // Define a generator and create the sequence
        auto generator = [n = 0]() mutable->std::string {return std::to_string((int)((1 + std::sqrt(1 + 8 * n++)) / 2)); };
        std::generate(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), generator);

        // Simple output
        std::copy(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nInvalid input\n";
}
```

And the 100'000'000th entry will be 14142, calculated without any loop . . .

Comment: Oh yes, that is the fancy stuff using a mutable lambda to create all the repeated characters. Also a good approach. But in my comment under the original questions I advised that I would use the simple nested loops manually so he could appreciate what the crafty library functions will be doing for him behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to put it into a string vector

You can use `std::vector::push_back` to add(push_back) more elements into a vector as shown below. Moreover, you can use `std::to_string` to convert the `int` to `std::string`. Also note that there is no need to create a `std::vector<int>`. You can just directly use `push_back` to push/add elements into `vecString` using `to_string` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

void print_vectorStr(const std::vector<std::string> &vec, std::string sep = "")
{
    std::cout << "\nThe vector string elements are: ";
    for (auto elem : vec)
    {
        std::cout << elem << sep;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    int n;
    std::cout << "insert n \n";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<std::string> vecString;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            
            vecString.push_back(std::to_string(i)); //add element into the vecString
        }
    }
    
    print_vectorStr(vecString, " ");//prints the required pattern

}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZEhosbmV9)